# Google+ Oauth 2.0 - Logout works well BUT automatically login after refreshing webpage

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, oauth, google-plus, logout

### Heading

I'm working on Google App Engine. Using Python with the webbapp2 framework.

I use Google API to login e logout. It seems to work well. Login and logout are perfect. This is the Google official guide: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

The problem is that just after being logged out refreshing the page the user will automatically logged-in again.

This is **Login Button** with relative parameters:

```
    <span
        class="g-signin"
        data-callback="signinCallback"
        data-clientid="##################.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
        <button type="button">GOOGLE+ LOGIN</button>
    </span>
```

This is **Logout Button**:

```
    <button onclick="disconnectUser()">Disconnect</button>
```

This is the **Logout callback function**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function disconnectUser(access_token) {
          var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +
              access_token;

          // Esecuzione di una richiesta GET asincrona.
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: revokeUrl,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(nullResponse) {
              // Esegui un'azione, l'utente è disconnesso
              // La risposta è sempre indefinita.

                document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: inherit');
                document.getElementById('revokeButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            },
            error: function(e) {
              // Gestione dell'errore
              // console.log(e);
              // Puoi indirizzare gli utenti alla disconnessione manuale in caso di esito negativo
              // https://plus.google.com/apps
            }
          });
        }
        // È possibile attivare la disconnessione con un clic del pulsante
        $('#revokeButton').click(disconnectUser);
    </script>
```

**What do you think? What could be the problem? Something concerning cookies setting?**

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I am having the same problem with gapi.auth.signOut().

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446803/google-login-how-to-logout-using-gapi-auth-signout/32892148#32892148)

Answer (score 4):

You should be calling `gapi.auth.signOut()` to sign out the user. Disconnect, as you are implementing here, will disconnect the user from your application and de-authorize your application to make API calls on behalf of the user. An example would be:

```
<button onclick="gapi.auth.signOut()">Sign out</button>
```

See [Signing out the user](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/sign-out) for more information on how to correctly sign out a user.

Also worth noting:

- If you are running from localhost, logout may not work.
- The Sign in callback is also called on failure: make sure to check that the error message is absent to check, i.e:

```js
    function signinCallback(authResult) {                                          
      if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {                                  
          // Signed in                                                            
        } else {                                                                  
          console.log('Sign-in failed: ' + authResult['error']);                  
        }                                                                         
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't signOut() work when running from localhost?  I am experiencing this now.  By work I the user is logged in automatically after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

If the logout isn't working on localhost for you, try saving the user you get after making the request and using the disconnect function on the user you got. Works like a charm for me, this method is nowhere documented as far as i know. That's also the reason why is just implemented both methods, just in case.

```js
var theUser = null;
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  theUser = googleUser //Please note that you should validate
                       //your user's token on the Server side
                       //if you are trying to save the id on the server
}

function onLogOut(){
  var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  auth2.signOut().then(function () {
    $('#logout').hide();
    $('#login').show();
  });
  theUser.disconnect();
}
```

To log in as another User afterwards you may need to refresh the page with something like this:

```
location.reload();
```